# Finding running .NET version on IIS apps

Tags: asp.net, .net, powershell, iis

I am currently working on a website being hosted on a server using IIS to manage the applications on it. I want to use a powershell script to find out what version of .NET each app is currently running. I have been trying to use the Web Admin module to find the .NET version but am struggling to find it.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to check the .NET Framework version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-the-net-framework-version)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128426/how-to-get-the-net-framework-version-that-the-application-is-using

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878633/how-to-check-net-website-version

Comment: These are all C# solves and I'm looking for a way to do this in PowerShell

Comment: What about [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265/powershell-script-to-return-versions-of-net-framework-on-a-machine)

Comment: This question on was asked in another article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265/powershell-script-to-return-versions-of-net-framework-on-a-machine

Comment: This is not the same question. I want it specifically for app on a server running IIS to manage a website. Not just the running version of .NET on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

very simple

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\full" /v version
```

then you will get this

```
version    REG_SZ    4.7.02556
```

Comment: I think OP wants to know each application's version (they might be using different version).

Comment: This gives me the version of framework being used by the VM not each app.

Comment: how about this, get .NET framework version of site running in IIS by PowerShell https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-get-NET-framework-4d7f7a45